# Deleting Row From Custom Cell UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have a tableview with custom cells. I am looking to make a button inside the custom cell and when I click it that it deletes that row and refreshes the main view with the new array. The array is gotten when the view loads from the userDefaults which are stored as shown below. The following code works if I comment out the delete rows line but it will refresh with the old array information and will not get the new array. I have tried everything and the current code is giving me the following error:

> -[TableViewCellSchedule section]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffd65092800

any ideas are appreciated.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:favid forKey:@"favid"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
TableViewCellSchedule *cell = (TableViewCellSchedule *)[[self.fullfav superview] superview];
UITableView *table = cell.superview;
[table reloadData];
[table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:cell]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: Print `[self.fullfav superview]`, `[[self.fullfav superview] superview]` and `cell.superview`. I wouldn't use that, to retrieve the view and I guess there is something wrong there.

Comment: @Larme using them it reloads the tableview data just fine, but its reloading it with the old information stored in the array and not the new information.

Comment: You reload data, then delete rows.   Imagine an array @[@1, @2, @3, @4]. If you try to remove row 2 , it will be @[@1, @3, @4], right?   If you reload data, the table view reloads, so it present @[@1, @3, @4]. Then you again try to remove row number 2 which means the row that has @3, which is inconsistent with your model

Comment: even commenting out the reloadData or moving it to the end the delete rows is still giving me the error. @user9335240

Comment: Don't use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` ... instead, set a callback in your cell's button (using a closure or a delegate) to tell your ViewController to *remove that item from the data array*. Then your ViewController calls reloadData.

Comment: Never call both `reloadData` and one of the `insert/delete/reloadRowsAtIndexPath`. Only use one or the other. And there is no need to call `synchronize`.

Comment: The problem not in `reloadData` or whaever, but the whole organisation of the code. You had to do this logic in `UIViewController` subclass (`UITableViewController` subclass perhaps). You had to have outlets to table view and use them to access tableView. You had to have `dataSource` and `delegate` to create and handle cells, and never reach them by any variations of `superview`.  After this is done you can consider reloading table and and  etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this approach for delete cell --

- First take table view add cell and add a button on this.
- Create a IBOutlet of button inside cell class.
- Create a IBAction inside your view controller class where table view datasource and delegate methods are present.
- Inside tableview method (cellForRowAtIndexPath) provide a tag value to this button. i.e. row number
- when a cell button is clicked you will get it's tag value inside IBAction of button.
- then you can delete row by remove this index from array.
- Then reload data.

> ```
> - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>         ContactTableViewCell *cell            = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
>  // your initialization -----------
>         cell.btnFriend.tag                = indexPath.row;
>         return cell;
>  }
>
> // this button is present on cell. By tag value of button we can get cell index which is selected, because tag value and array index is same
> - (IBAction)tapOnUnfriend:(id)sender
> {
>     UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
>     NSString *strSelectedTitle = [arrMyFriendList objectAtIndex :btn.tag];
>    [arrMyFriendList removeObjectAtIndex:btn.tag];
>    [self.tableViewContactList reloadData];
>
>  // or if you  want cell of tableview you can get by tag value
>  // NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btn.tag inSection:0];
> // YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)[tblRegister cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
>
> }
> ```

Comment: How do I add the IBAction inside the view controller class? Thought I could only add that into the cell class as the button is inside the cell class

Comment: try to drag button action in view controller, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's **not** a good practice to get your `cell` by doing `[[self.fullfav superview] superview];` High chance that you may end up with something else than a cell. Instead work with your tableview datasource/delegate methods and your data source array to keep your tableview synced.

Your code is crashing because of this line `[table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:cell]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`

It's because `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` method accepts an array of `NSIndexPath` objects but you're passing in an array of `TableViewCellSchedule` object. So the array you need to pass to that method should be like this - `[NSArray arrayWithObject:[table indexPathForCell:cell]]`. Also remove `reloadData` method if you're using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`

Comment: Tried that and I get the following error 2018-03-05 17:20:30.364220+0000 UAReloaded[10922:241062] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.33.6/UITableView.m:2011
2018-03-05 17:20:30.376020+0000 UAReloaded[10922:241062] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update

Comment: @CurtisBoylan Remove the `reloadData` method. Also, where is your datasource being set and who calls this method, where is it located?

Comment: "First of all, it's not a good practice to get your cell " - indeed. Not good - is to name variable `fullfav` cause it is not informative. Code above is **not good** in the way as to drive car upside down, to jumping on trampoline beneath rotating helicopter.

Comment: I agree @MichaelVorontsov My answer was aimed to solve OPs crash for sending in a wrong data type to a method. The best way to remove this cell would be working with tableview's datasource and delegate methods, instead of calling superviews

Comment: @theCoderGuy yeap, I just want to stress what do you mean by "not good"

Comment: @theCoderGuy being set in the viewcontroller. My code is in the custom cell though. I removed the reloadData and get the same crash

Comment: @CurtisBoylan I need to  see your viewcontroller and custom cell codes please. Let's move this conversation to chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166316/deleting-row-from-custom-cell-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example. Assuming you have a `UITableViewController` with a prototype cell that looks like this:

[image]

and you have the label connected to an IBOutlet, and Touch Up Inside on the button connected to an IBAction...

---

Cell.h

```
//
//  RemoveRowTableViewCell.h
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 3/5/18.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RemoveRowTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *theLabel;

- (void)setDidTapDeleteButtonBlock:(void (^)(id sender))didTapDeleteButtonBlock;

@end
```

---

Cell.m

```
//
//  RemoveRowTableViewCell.m
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 3/5/18.
//

#import "RemoveRowTableViewCell.h"

@interface  RemoveRowTableViewCell ()

@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^didTapDeleteButtonBlock)(id sender);

@end

@implementation RemoveRowTableViewCell

- (IBAction)doDidTapDeleteButton:(id)sender {
    // call back to tell the table view controller that the button was tapped
    if (self.didTapDeleteButtonBlock) {
        self.didTapDeleteButtonBlock(sender);
    }
}

@end
```

---

TableViewController.h

```
//
//  RemoveRowTableViewController.h
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 3/5/18.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RemoveRowTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

---

TableViewController.m

```
//
//  RemoveRowTableViewController.m
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 3/5/18.
//

#import "RemoveRowTableViewController.h"
#import "RemoveRowTableViewCell.h"

@interface RemoveRowTableViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *theDataArray;
@end

@implementation RemoveRowTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // initialize the data array
    self.theDataArray = [@[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G"] mutableCopy];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _theDataArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RemoveRowTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"removeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.theLabel.text = _theDataArray[indexPath.row];

    [cell setDidTapDeleteButtonBlock:^(id sender) {
        // button in cell was tapped, so remove that item from the data array
        [self.theDataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // and reload the tableView
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Now, when you tap on the button in the cell, it will "call back" to the block defined in tableViewController, where the code will remove that row's element from the data array, and the table view will be reloaded.